# c++ program crashes when "free" memory is zero but standby-memory is still available

Tags: c++, out-of-memory

I have a bit of a problem:

I need to load around 260mb of data into a struct (with fread). Windows Resource-Management tells me that I have:

- 2346mb memory in use
- 1478mb memory in standby
- 248mb memory free

However, when I run my program and load the data the program crashes at the point where no more "free" memory is left. There are still around 1200mb of standby memory left.

I thought, when the free mem is empty it will automatically swap the standby-memory to the disk and free more memory?

Is there any way to avoid this problem or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Is it a 32-bit program?  If so, you only get at most 2-3 GB of virtual address space, no matter how much physical memory or swap space you have.

Comment: could you update some code where you allocates memory? Memory usage in Windows Resource-Management doesn't really matter for your case as all windows 32bit process has its own 4GB virtual memory space (1~2GB reserved for system though).

Answer (score 5):

Just because the memory is available doesn't mean it's contiguous. When you ask for a big chunk like that, you're unlikely to get it because the available memory is fragmented.

Comment: Contiguous memory is only important for DMA buffers.  Contiguous address space, on the other hand...

Answer (score 1):

You're exhausting your virtual address space, not physical memory.  As you guessed, physical memory would be augmented be shrinking the disk cache and then by using the swapfile.  Virtual address space is a hard limit, however.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try changing Virtual memory page file size from system properties.
2. At the start of the program allocate all required memory. (Memory Pool concept)
3. Restart you system and try again